# Download Artifacts from Bamboo Ondemand

Tags: bamboo, jira-ondemand

I am trying to build and deploy a .NET web application using Bamboo OnDemand. Built successfully but I am struggling to find a way to deploy the artifacts to one of our internal server. And I cant open the firewall.

I tried Bamboo [CLI's getArtifact](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/BCLI/Documentation) command but it could only download specified file, not the entire package. I also could not find a way to zip the artifacts onDemand so I could use the above command.

If anyone has overcome similar situation, then please help. Any clue/advise will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve this, here are a couple. Both options require that you have a zip tool available on the server to do zipping. I use 7za.exe (command line version of [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html))

This file is checked into the repository so that bamboo downloads it with your sources and your can access it from scripts or msbuild

1 - Add a Script task after the build task. I run it as a powershell inline script similar to this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "bamboo.build.working.directory\7za.exe" -ArgumentList "a","pathToYourArchive.zip", "folderToZip\*" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Add a script task which zips the build output, and drops it in a location which you configure as a build artifact.

2 - Customize your release build configuration in msbuild to do the zipping

Modify your .csproj file, and uncomment the AfterBuild target. Use an Exec task to launch 7za, or use a custom task such as [msbuild extension pack](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack)

1 is probably faster option, but as a best practice I would put any scripting into a ps1 file that is source controlled, and then modify the script to call into the ps1 file. That way you can version your build code.